# 【FuelPHP】モジュールを使った時の共通ライブラリ＆ビジネスロジックの設計について

Tags: php, fuelphp

FuelPHPのバージョンは1.8です。

siteというFuelプロジェクトの構成を下記とします（省略してるフォルダもあります）

fuel/
　|- app/
　|　|- logs/
　|　|- classes/
　|　|　　|------- controller/
　|　|　　|------- model/
　|　|- config/
　|　|- views/
　|　|- modules/
　|　　　　|------- admin_module
　|　　　　|------- site_admin_module
　|- core/
　|- packages/
　public/

siteという一般的なWebサービスを作り
他のサービスでも使いたい汎用管理画面をadmin_modulesに、siteサービスに特化した管理画面をsite_admin_modulesに
（設計都合で汎用と特化で管理画面を二つに分けてます）
のようなモジュール設計を考えてます。

□ 質問1
app下のclassesやmodules内のclasses
で共通して使いたいライブラリ、例えばutilクラスや汎用apiなど（mvcの構成はとらないもの）
はどこに配置すればベストでしょうか？
（他fuelphpで作成したサービスにも使いたいライブラリです）

□ 質問2
model配下にはorm¥modelなどのActiveRecordを作りますが、
純粋なビジネスロジック（ActiveRecord以外）はどこに配置すればいいのでしょうか？
（やはりmodel/でしょうか?）

utilなどはpackagesに置けばいいのか疑問な部分です。

以上、ご教授お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FuelPHPの枠内で考える場合と、FuelPHPの枠に捉われずに配置する2つの方法が考えられます。

## FuelPHPの枠内で考える場合

質問1は、packagesです。
FuelPHPでのパッケージというのは再利用するライブラリということですから。
http://fuelphp.jp/docs/1.8/general/packages.html

質問2は、modelです。純粋なビジネスロジックはMVCで考えるならモデルだからです。
また、もともとFuelPHPの標準のModelクラスは空のクラスであることからわかるように、FuelPHPはモデルを広く捉えています。

## FuelPHPの枠に捉われない場合

いずれも、[PSR-4](http://qiita.com/inouet/items/0208237629496070bbd4) に従い、任意のわかりやすい場所に配置し、Composerのオートローダを設定してください。

http://blog.a-way-out.net/blog/2014/06/17/fuelphp-psr-model/
に一例があります。

この場合は、ライブラリをComposerのパッケージにすることも可能です。